# How can i get cluster info just like on the terminal, but on my c# client (stackexchange)?

Tags: c#, redis, client, cluster-computing

I'm trying to get cluster info of my cluster in Redis on C# with stackexchange library.
I just can't find info about it.
The output I'm trying to get is just on the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXdzS.jpg).

Example:

```
127.0.0.1:7005> 
  cluster info 
  cluster_state:ok 
  cluster_slots_assigned:16384 
  cluster_slots_ok:16384 
  cluster_slots_pfail:0 
  cluster_slots_fail:0 
  cluster_known_nodes:6 
  cluster_size:3 
  cluster_current_epoch:7 
  cluster_my_epoch:1 
  cluster_stats_messages_ping_sent:8420 
  cluster_stats_messages_pong_sent:6418 
  cluster_stats_messages_sent:14838
```

Comment: Post that example of cluster info as text

Comment: i dont know how to do it. sorry

Comment: But you already did it in comment to answer. I moved it to your question. Some entries are missing (in comparison with image), so I didn't remove link to image, but if they're important add them and remove that image link from question

Answer (score 0):

it is actually pretty simple. Use the `Info` method on `IServer` as follows.

```
ConnectionMultiplexer pool = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1:6379, allowAdmin=true");
var infoResult = pool.GetServer("127.0.0.1:6379").Info();
```

Keep in mind that you need to allow `adminMode` in order to be allowed to call the `Info` API.

Comment: It is not what i need unfortunately.
this gives me a lot of info about 1 server. what I need is the Cluster info, like this:
127.0.0.1:7005> cluster info
cluster_state:ok
cluster_slots_assigned:16384
cluster_slots_ok:16384
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:6
cluster_size:3
cluster_current_epoch:7
cluster_my_epoch:1
cluster_stats_messages_ping_sent:8420
cluster_stats_messages_pong_sent:6418
cluster_stats_messages_sent:14838
...